# How to create R worker subprocesses that can perform long task while the parent R process is kept active

Tags: r, shiny, worker

Consider a R shiny application that can initiate long calculus (let say one day calculus).
I would like this application to transfer the long calculus to a worker R process and to continue to serve other requests. When the calculus is done the shiny application can then access the result though a cache or something equivalent.
A generic shiny server.R function would be something like that

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){

  queryString <- reactive({GetQueryString(input)})
  observe({LanchWorkerProcess(queryString())})
  output$result <- renderText({ GetCachedResult(queryString()) }) 

})
```

This kind of pattern is common in some languages such as [Node.js](http://neilk.net/blog/2013/04/30/why-you-should-use-nodejs-for-CPU-bound-tasks/).  There are significant resources for parallel computing in R [(CRAN HighPerformanceComputing)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html), and I have identified some precious building blocks like [rRedis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rredis/index.html) and [doRedis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRedis/index.html). Yet I am not sure how to put the building blocks together and I am afraid to be trying to reinvent the wheel.

How could this pattern be implemented in a smart way ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Rdsm package, it allows for distributed memory so that multiple R processes can share variables.  Use it along with a package for doing parallel processing, like parallel, snow, or Rmpi, to send messages between the processes to run the code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The Rdsm package is indeed another useful building block for this problem. I will try to put all this together.